# Odoo Server Error

Tags: python, database, postgresql, odoo

Whenever I try to install a module in Odoo I get a wall of text like this:

---

Odoo Server Error

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 952, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 940, in _call_kw
    return checked_call(request.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 939, in checked_call
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 446, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 494, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 901, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 987, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 853, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 763, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1077, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/product/product.py", line 1181, in create
    return super(product_product, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 381, in create
    thread_id = super(mail_thread, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 336, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4083, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 463, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4139, in _create
    record_id = self.pool[table].create(cr, user, tocreate[table], context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/product/product.py", line 730, in create
    product_template_id = super(product_template, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 381, in create
    thread_id = super(mail_thread, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 336, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4083, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 463, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4221, in _create
    tuple([u[2] for u in updates if len(u) > 2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 158, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 234, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
```

**ParseError: "null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (16, null, null, 1.00, null, 0, null, 1, fixed, 1, null, 2015-10-06 12:46:43.109221, 1.000, 1, t, 1, null, null, 1, null, 1, null, null, null, null, 2015-10-06 12:46:43.109221, t, f, null, null, consu, null, f, null, f, null, null, f, 7, t).
" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/hr_timesheet/hr_timesheet_data.xml:15, near**

```
<record id="product.product_product_consultant" model="product.product">
            <field name="sale_ok">True</field>
        </record>
```

**How do I fix this?** I have full access to the server (it's running ubuntu server 14.04), got a superuser for PostgreSQL as well as for Odoo.

I thought about editing the database and removing that one line from the database table, but no luck so far.

**edit01:** One thing that might be relevant, although it already is written inside the text: The problem appeared first when trying to install the `hr_timesheet`-Addon. It doesn't show the install/installed button anymore either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a 'name' value for your product XML declaration:

```
<field name="name">Name of your product</field>
```

Comment: I have a `<field name="name">Timesheet Journal</field>`, it's inside the `usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/hr_timesheet/hr_timesheet_data.xml`
Does that mean I need a second field? Or which XML would you be talking about?

Comment: I just added it "near" the record it showed me and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce this in your .xml file, just add the new field with the name="name" and works like charm:

```
<record id="product.product_product_consultant" model="product.product">
        <field name="sale_ok">True</field>
        <field name="name">hr_timesheet-8.0.1.0</field>
    </record>
```